# Docker - Detached and Interactive?

Tags: docker

When reading different books, articles and forum threads I often saw the `docker run` command as follows:

```
docker run -tid <dockerimage>
```

What I really don't understand: Does it make sense to start a *detached* (-d) Container *interactive* (-i) with *pseudo tty* (-t) ?

I mean a detached Container will never prompt you to a console so I don't think it's necessary to call it with `-it`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you `docker run` an image with only `-d` option, the container will exit immediately after the command executed. If you `docker run` with `-itd` option, the container will be detached but running in background, and you can attach back when you need. See the screenshot attached for more clarity.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, perfect explanation and demo.

Comment: The important point I miss in this answer is the reason why the container exists immediately in the first case, with `-d` option (well explained in @Joshua Chia's answer): The container exists because /bin/bash exits. And /bin/bash exits because stdin is no longer open. In the second case, with `-itd` option, docker keeps the stdin of bash open, ready for you to attach again.

Answer (score 52):

`-i` (interactive) is about whether to keep stdin open (some programs, like bash, use stdin and other programs don't). `-d` (detached) is about whether the `docker run` command waits for the process being run to exit. Thus, they are orthogonal and not inherently contradictory. A program like bash exits when stdin is closed, so without `-i`, it exits immediately.

`-t` (tty) allocates a pseudo-tty. You can see the difference from running bash with `-it` vs with just `-i`. For example, without -t, you don't get any prompt and `ls` shows results in one column. This difference is like the difference between running `ls` from a normal bash session and running `ls | cat` from a normal bash session, where `cat` does not have a pseudo-tty.

When you `docker run` bash in a container, `-it` and `-itd` behave differently as follows:

- With `-it`, `docker run` gives you the bash prompt immediately.
- With `-itd`, `docker run` exits immediately, but you can `docker attach` after that and get the bash prompt just as if you had just done `docker run -it`.

Comment: After debugging an issue of a stuck container for hours, this answer saved my day. Thanks a lot! (actually I was doing -d, but not -itd so it stopped working after one printf)

Comment: Should be the accepted answer. Thank you for clarifying what -i does and the fact that containers will exist when the entrypoint executable does and how bash,sh etc operate.

Answer (score 2):

I think that in general starting up a detached interactive container like this is an unusual use case. It's certainly nothing I ever end up using in my daily use of docker.

Some applications may behave differently when their stdout is associated with a tty vs when it's not (e.g., they may only log to stdout by default when their output is a terminal, or if you're running a shell it may simply exit when not associated with a terminal).

You may want to `docker attach` to the running container.  This is especially important if you've started some sort of detached shell.