# How to attach to a docker-compose container?

Tags: docker

When I start a container as following:

```
docker run --name test -itd busybox
```

I can attach to it with:

```
docker attach test
```

I can now execute commands, such as `ls`, and see the results. Great!

Now, I want to start my container via a `docker-compose.yml` instead. I tried with:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  busybox:
    image: busybox
    tty: true
```

With this, when I attach to the container again with `docker attach <container id>`, I seem to be able to "connect" to it, but I don't see any output when executing a command (for example `ls`).

Why is that? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to replicate the -i and -t flags. with `tty` yo did the -t. For the `-i` flag, add stdin_open to your docker-compose.yaml.

```
stdin_open: true
tty: true
```

Comment: Oh, right! I wrongly assumed that `tty: true` was the equivalent of `-it`. I did not really realize that `-it` actually contains two flags.

Comment: Scratching my head for a while on this one, I kept going down the wrong rabbit holes, but this was the only answer that worked. Thanks!

Comment: @geerlingguy, just in case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40026942/5113030 (*Confused about Docker -t option to Allocate a pseudo-TTY*...); https://stackoverflow.com/q/35459652/5113030 (*When would I use --interactive without --tty in a Docker container?*...); https://stackoverflow.com/q/47753047/5113030 (*Docker - Detached and Interactive?*...)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try `docker exec -it <container id> bash` because `docker attach` ["only" attaches your terminal’s standard input, output, and error](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/attach/).

Comment: I don't want to start a new shell, I want to attach to the running process.

Answer (score 0):

Another slightly more mnemonic option is to use [`docker compose logs --follow`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_logs/). You can specify or exclude specific services with `--attach` and `--no-attach` respectively.

This does not actually help with this specific problem, because it **only allows to read program output and not send input**, but since this is the first thing I found when searching for my problem and it's reasonably related, I'll still put this here in case someone else finds it useful.