# Docker Container immediately exists even I execute it with -dit

Tags: docker, jenkins, containers

My docker container immediately exists after I run it with command -dit .. I do not understand why it happens. I am running my container with sh command in the Jenkins file which is executed in the Jenkins. You can find out the actual code below. I see that unable to find the container after I execute with the command "docker exec" as you will see below. Even I list the containers with docker ps -a command I can see the docker container exited in 1 second. Do you think I made a mistake while executing docker run -d -I -t command ?

```
 def containerName = myContainer
 def imageName= buildedImage

 sh "docker run -d -i -t --name $containerName $imageName"
 sh "docker ps -a"
 sh "docker exec -it $containerName /bin/bash \"/target/scripts/dockertest.sh\""
```

My Dockerfile is :

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE
ADD ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Xmx128m","-Xss256k","-XX:+UseG1GC","-     Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Comment: What's the command executed when you run the container ? Can you show your `Dockerfile` ?

Comment: Also note that [the Jenkins Docker plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#building-containers) has specific support for running steps inside containers: you can run `docker.inside(imageName)` to do the setup, and then `sh` can get run inside that container.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47753047/docker-detached-and-interactive

Comment: hello Mickael sorry for being late. I added the Dockerfile in the question. I have edited the question. any help would be kindly accepted.thank you

Comment: @MickaelB I already runned it with -dit . I think running with -itd is same by running with -dit.

Comment: hello @David can you please give a sample such like docker.inside(imageName) then docker run?  any help will be appreciated..

Comment: Are you sure that your program uses stdin ? Cause if it doesn't then there is no point in keeping it open the program will just execute and and terminate without waiting.

Comment: Nope I am not using stdin @MickaelB. Could you please provide a sample commend for that Mickael ?

Comment: Commands like `cat` or `/bin/bash` reads stdin. What is your program `app.jar` doing ? And what does your `dockertest.sh` do ?

Comment: Hello @MickaelB. app.jar is a local tar archive in a recognized compression format (identity, gzip, bzip2 or xz) then it is unpacked as a directory. Resources from remote URLs are not decompressed.     dockertest.sh executes some goss scripts for instance which checked if the application url is working or not

Comment: do you think /bin/bash command is not working properly ? as a result of that as you said the project will execute and terminate without waiting. Bu  somehow sh "docker ps -a" also is not able to list the working containers

Comment: What are you trying to do with this `java` command ?

Comment: `/bin/bash` works fine you are just not using it since you use `java`

Comment: @MickaelB by typing "java", “-jar" in the ENTRYPOINT of docker file I want Docker to run the jar by using java -jar and the jar name

Comment: so you believe that if I remove java then I will be using /bin/bash and the container will be alive because of the fact that I will be using stdin.

Comment: What does the `/app.ar` do ??? ?

Comment: Just put all your commands in the `Dockerfile` and don't use `docker exec`. It will work !

Comment: hello @MickaelB. Thanks for your helps. I resolved it by the help of you. The thing is parameters  'ADD'  and 'ENTRYPOINT'  defined in the Dockerfile are not required. That somehow caused problems which I do not understand but I will search but when I add these parameters on the Dockerfile it does not make container work. Thank you for your kindest helps.