# specify interactive explicitly in docker run

Tags: docker

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47753047/docker-detached-and-interactive) nicely explains difference between detached (`-d`) and interactive (`-i`). The answer says:

> -i (interactive) is about whether to keep stdin open (some programs, like bash, use stdin and other programs don't). -d (detached) is about
>   whether the docker run command waits for the process being run to
>   exit. Thus, they are orthogornal and not inherently contradictory. A
>   program like bash exits when stdin in closed, so without -i, it exits
>   immediately.

Assume that I have some command which does not require opened STDIN. Then what is the difference between using `-it` and not using `-it`? Is there any difference e.g. in following two commands?

```
docker run ubuntu tail -f /etc/passwd
docker run -it ubuntu tail -f /etc/passwd
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the docker run command documentation

```
--interactive , -i  : Keep STDIN open even if not attached
```

```
--tty , -t          : Allocate a pseudo-TTY
```

I thought that the only difference between executing with -it or not in your case is that will runs Docker interactively and through pseudo-TTY